# Как повторить выполнение команды в случае исключения

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, grab

Имеется такой код, нужно повторить его в случае если будет исключение

```
try:

    sleep(3)

    g.response.body

except GrabTimeoutError
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зацикливаем код:

```
while True:
    try:
        sleep(3)
        g.response.body

        # Исключения не было, выходим из цикла
        break
    
    except GrabTimeoutError as e:
        ...
```

---

**PS.** [Тут есть похожий пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8f27b7807258a63fa2da1254647bf4245cf2c67c/incremental%20timeouts.py) с инкрементальной задержкой между повторами